# regedit - Libre office 5 how to disable auto-updates in

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice, regedit

I currently need to find a regedit entry so i can disable libre office 5 auto-updates. Does anyone has a sollution?

OS: **Windows 7 64x professional**.

Comment: I don't find registry. Libreoffice modifies a file in `%AppData%\LibreOffice\4\user` and the file name is `registrymodifications.xcu`.

Comment: i have not founded needed string except this ones:
"Needs update" and "UpdateCheck", that does not realy solves the problem with disabling the updates.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, that is not possible.  I have seen it stated all you can do is uninstall, then reinstall with the correct options to the msi to prevent auto update.

It seems to be a per user setting, so fixing it for one user seems to work, but only until someone else logs into the station.

See here for one such discussion
https://github.com/somedowntime/libreofficegrouppolicy/issues/4